# get table cell data from and place a copy in another table

Tags: php, jquery, html, database

Two-part question:
I have two tables: one table is items and the other is the table that selected items will be copied into when the Add button is clicked. After, when all items that are wanted are selected, there will be a 'finished' button which will post the items selected to the DB.

I started with Javascript but didn't get far at all because jQuery seems better suited but I'm not very familiar with it

```
 function addto()
 {
var div = document.getElementById('fixedDiv','inside');

div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'Item Added';

 }

<div id='fixedDiv'> 

<table align="center" id="tradee">
    <th rowspan="2"> Other Item</th>


    <?php while($rowi =$item->fetch_assoc())
    {?>

    <tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $rowi['item_name']; ?>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $rowi['item_description'];?></td>

    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

```
    <br>
        <table align="center" id="tradeTable">
        <th>Cat_id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    <?php while($row =$item_results->fetch_assoc())
    {?>

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $cat_id = $row['cat_id']; ?> </td>

        <td name="item_name"><?php echo $item_id = $row['item_name'];?></td>

        <td><?php echo $item_descrip = $row['item_description'];?></td>

        <td><input name ="submit" type="button" class="added" onclick="addto()" 
        value="Add" >
        </td>

        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    </table>
```

Comment: can you provide us with a fiddle with a sample of your markup?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net, add your HTML and Javascsript, click save and share us the link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GaE6P/ 
never used jsfiddle but there's PHP too in the code. Not sure if it makes a difference or not

Comment: no PHP is not supported, you should include your markup as it is rendered in the browser, that is after PHP has run

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4FArt/
What a great site

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5EcNj/ updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know what excatly you try to do, but i hope it helps a bit:

Here is the fiddle with some **modifications on your html** and jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/4FArt/5/

```
function addto(obj)
{
    var $row = $(obj).parents("tr");
    var $table = $("#tradee");
    var item_name = $row.find(".item-name").text();
    var item_desc = $row.find(".item-desc").text();

    var newTR = $("<tr><td>"+item_name+"</td><td>"+item_desc+"</td></tr>");
    $table.append(newTR);

}
```

You should check also your markup of HTML, a `TD` has no `name` Attribute, and ah `<TH>` is also wrapped by an `<TR>`... But maybe its just for showing, and you allready know that :)

Comment: use `closest()` instead of `parents()` to stop searching after the first match

Comment: @reyaner It is just for showing. I ran the code and its what I'm trying to do but the add only works for the first three items

Comment: yes, i didnt set class: item-name etc. on all td's... sry... ;)

Comment: maybe you should load jquery... like in fiddle:
`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript">` or from google or download it

Comment: shit, I thought this was javascript. I'm sorry. feel like a fool now